# Bouncy Castle : invalid armor IOException

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gpg-signature

I am currently using bouncy-gpg --> v2.3.0,
bcpg-jdk15on --> v1.59 and bcprov-jdk15on --> v1.65 maven dependencies. The decryption works perfectly fine with the encrypted input file. But on bumping version of bcpg-jdk15on to 1.65, it starts throwing exception, i.e., invalid armor.
I am unable to figure out what is causing the compatibility issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.